# Mail not sending values PHP

Tags: php

For some reason when I try to send the values listed below, I get nothing in return. I'll appreciate some help on the matter. Thanks.

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="email_script.php">
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="12u$">
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="12u$">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u$">
            <ul class="actions align-center">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" value="Reset Form" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My PHP Script (just echoing the data for debugging)

```
<?php
  $to = 'myemail@domain.com';
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $Body = "Name:\n$name\n\n";
  $Body .= "subject :\n$subject \n\n";
  $Body .= "email :\n$email \n\n";
  $Body .= "message:\n$message\n\n";

  echo $Body;

?>
```

Sorry guys. It was an .htaccess rule that was causing the issues.

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: And what's the output?

Comment: Are you sure that the little PHP script is called `email_script.php` and is located in the correct folder

Comment: It's mostly blank, consisting of just: Name: subject: email: message:

Comment: var_dump($_POST) check is getting anything after submit?

Comment: The script is located in the root. No possible directory issues.

Comment: Are you using the same script to display the form and process the submission?

Comment: Different locations. The form is located on "contact.html" and the script is on "email_script.php". Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, remove the value="" from the inputs and see if something changes.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis, I tried that. Still nothing.

Comment: What are the results of the var_dump($_POST)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use

```
<form method="post" action="email_script.php">    
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="12u$">
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="12u$">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u$">
            <ul class="actions align-center">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" value="Reset Form" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

> Check working script at
>   http://main.xfiddle.com/7ffb488b/stackoverflow/contact.php or http://main.xfiddle.com/7ffb488b/stackoverflow/contact.html

Comment: The location isn't the issue. The script is executing via the submit form properly because it's echoing some of the data, just not all of it.

Comment: And OP states form is `contact.html` so how is `<?php` executed?  Just delete please.

Comment: @JoshuaAdams check answered link its working properly.

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap, I'm using an .html file extension so I don't think that would work.

Comment: i used both .php and .html you can replace .php to .html it also would work

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap, I didn't notice your Xfiddle links. Those are working properly.  Thank you. However, I switched the file extension to .php and mine still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new PHP installation? If so $_POST uploads requires that you set correctly this 3 setings.

1. upload_max_filesize
2. post_max_size
3. memory_limit

This is should be in your php.ini try to set them to 2048M and see if it work
(you may need to restart apache: sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart)

Comment: It was a .htaccess rule that was causing the issue. Sorry about that.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found the root of it.